# Why a function with compact support vanishes on the boundary of its domain

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

A function has compact support if its support is a compact set, while the support of a function $u:G\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is defined to be
$$\mathrm{supp}(u)=\overline{\{x\in G\mid u(x)\neq0\}}.$$
Lately, a statement said that

> If a function has compact support, it vanishes on the boundary of its domain.

So, how does this implication come up? Is there anyone who can prove it?

Thanks.

Comment: Depends on what *vanishes* means exactly, I think. Outside the support the function is by definition $0$. But there can be a sequence $(x_n)$ that converges to a boundary point of the support but for which $f(x_n) \not\to 0$ - take for example the function that is $1$ on $[0,1]$ and $0$ everywhere else. Maybe it was implicitly assumed that the function is *continuous* and has compact support...

Comment: I think $\textit{vanishes}$ means $f(x)=0$, for $x$ at boundaries of its domain.

So, do you mean that the statement should be
"if a continuous function has compact support, it vanished at boundaries of its domain."?

But, still I cannot get how this implication can work.

Comment: Dear barrymikhael, You should provide more context.  For example, is $f$ considered to be continuous, or smooth?  And is the domain an open set, say in $\mathbb R^n$?  Regards,

Answer (score 17):

Suppose that $G$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$, and that $f: G \to \mathbb R$ has compact support.  Then there is a compact subset $K \subset G$ such that
$f$ vanishes on $G\setminus K$.  Since $F:= \mathbb R^n \setminus G$ is closed, and $K$ is compact,
the distance between any point of $K$ and $F$ is bounded below by some $\epsilon >0$.  In particular, at any point of $G$ that is within distance $\epsilon$ of $\partial G$, the function $f$ will be zero (since such a point lies outside $K$).

---

Note that we can't literally evaluate $f$ at points of $\partial G$, since these
don't lie in $G$, so the statement that $f$ vanishes on the boundary of $G$ should be understood in a slightly figurative sense.

On the other hand, if $f$ were continuous, or smooth, and we extended $f$ to all of $\mathbb R^n$ by defining it be zero on $F$, this extended function would continue to be continuous, or smooth, and would vanish on $\partial G$.

Comment: Aha! I was horribly confused by your answer, until I re-read the question and saw that it says "if a function has compact support is vanishes on the boundary of it's *domain*". Somehow I had read "... boundary of it's *support*" there :-(. So this is the correct answer then, and mine is rather off-topic ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your input above Matt. But, since you have provide general answer for my unspecific question, I think I don't need to edit my question. However, I'm still trying to digest your answer, what is $f|G\backslash K$ means? Anyway, thanks Matt :D

Comment: @barrymikhael: Dear barrymikhael, There was a typo, now fixed. (I had meant to write "$f_{|G\setminus K}$ vanishes", i.e. that the restriction of $f$ to $G\setminus K$ vanishes.  I have now just written it out in English.  Regards,

Comment: @matt-e: Dear Matt, I have questions, why this statement "$f:G\rightarrow R$ has compact support. Then there is a compact subset $K\subset G$ such that $f$ vanishes on $G\backslash K$" holds? can you prove it? and for $f\in C^\infty$ and there is a compact subset $K\subset G$ such that $f$ vanishes on $G\backslash K$ does $f$ necessarily holds $f(\partial G)=0$, where $\partial G$ is the boundary of $G$?

Comment: @barrymikhael: Dear barrymikhael, The support of $f$ is a compact subset $K$ of $G$ by assumption, and by definition $f$ vanishes on $G\setminus K$.  As I wrote in my answer, $\partial G$ is not contained in $G$ if $G$ is open, so it doesn't make literal sense to evaluate $f$ on points of $\partial G$.  Regards,

Comment: I misread your answer before, now I understand it completely, thanks :)

Comment: Your first statement seems strange. How can you suppose that $G$ is an open subset if it has compact support?