# What is the support of the solution

Tags: linear-algebra, maxima-minima

I am following "Sparse and redundant representations - from theory to application in image and signal processing" by Michael Elad.

Let $A\in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$ and $m>n$.

On the beginning of the third chapter:

"Looking at the problem ($P_0$):

$$P_0: \min_{x} \|x\|_0 \text{ subject to } Ax=b$$

one observes that the unknown $x$ is composed of two effective parts to be found
– the support of the solution, and the non-zero values over this support."

I cannot find the meaning behind "the support of the solution".

If I understand correctly, as we are looking at the $\ell_0-norm$, we are trying to find the vector $x$ containing a minimum number of non-zeroes which answers $Ax=b$. In other words, A linear combination of  some of the columns in $A$. Is it correct to say that the support is the set of columns in $A$ used for the linear combination?

Comment: I assume they mean support as in compact support of functions.

Comment: as in this sense: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/787719/why-compact-support-implies-a-function-vanished-at-boundaries

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)

Comment: I would propose taking at least some beginners course in Fourier Analysis or Transform Theory if you haven't already. There you are bound to learn it.

Comment: By the way do you have any link to Elad's course?

Comment: Have you even tried reading any of the links?

Comment: All I could find was [this](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~elad/publications/others/PCMI2010-Elad.pdf). I myself have the book (not online).

Comment: I am going through them now.